# Ensure calculating an aggregate only on rows which do have links throughout all 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Technical problem: Have 3 linked tables (the links are 1-to-many and many-to-many), need to calculate an aggregate on the first table, which links as 1-to-many to the second table, and the aggregate has to be calculated *only* on those items for which all the links in all the three tables are in place.

The same problem with business flavours, in short: I'm attempting to output all the menu positions for which all the ingredients already have a buy document already, and this list of menu positions should include a prime cost column calculated as an aggregate based on the price of the ingredients in that latest buy document.

I'm going to union that list with another select which deals with the menu positions where at least one of the ingredients doesn't have a buy document yet.

The closest I've got to so far is (I understand the query is long, but I believe it's still feasible to do what I want in one go, and it's not going to be underperforming):

```
(select hw_marketable.name as nm, hw_productcategory.name as pc, hw_marketable.price as p,
        round(sum(hw_inputopcrf.price*hw_prodcrf.spendquantity)::numeric, 2)::text as primecost,
        (case round(hw_marketable.price::numeric, 2) when 0.00 then '--' else                         round((sum(hw_inputopcrf.price*hw_prodcrf.spendquantity)*100./hw_marketable.price::real)::numeric, 2)::text
         end) as primecost_percentage,
        (case hw_marketable.enabled when 0 then 'Inactive' else 'Active' end)
 from hw_marketable inner join hw_prodcrf on marketableid=hw_marketable.id
      inner join hw_product on hw_product.id=productid
      inner join hw_inputopcrf on hw_inputopcrf.stapleid=hw_product.id
      inner join hw_inputop on hw_inputop.id=hw_inputopcrf.inputopid and
      hw_inputop.id=(
          select inputop2.id from hw_inputop as inputop2, hw_inputopcrf as inputopcrf2, hw_prodcrf as prodcrf2, hw_marketable as marketable2
          where inputop2.id=inputopcrf2.inputopid and inputopcrf2.stapleid=prodcrf2.productid
                and prodcrf2.marketableid=marketable2.id and marketable2.name=hw_marketable.name
          order by dateclosed desc limit 1)
      inner join hw_productcategory on hw_productcategory.id=hw_marketable.productcategoryid
 group by hw_marketable.id, nm, pc, p)

              union

(select hw_marketable.name as nm, hw_productcategory.name as pc, hw_marketable.price as p,
                   '-', '(no buy documents yet)',
        (case hw_marketable.enabled when 0 then 'Inactive' else 'Active' end)
 from hw_marketable inner join hw_prodcrf on marketableid=hw_marketable.id
      inner join hw_product on hw_product.id=productid
      inner join hw_productcategory on hw_productcategory.id=hw_marketable.productcategoryid
 where hw_product.id not in (select distinct stapleid from hw_inputopcrf))

 order by nm asc;
```

It seems to be summing up the prime cost fine, but it still fails to determine if at least one of the ingredients has a link in hw_inputopcrf, which links the buy documents with the ingredients.

A brief legend:

- **hw_marketable** - menu positions
- **hw_product** - ingredients
- **hw_inputop** - buy documents
- **hw_prodcrf** - cross-reference table to link
  hw_marketable and hw_product - illustrates which ingredients comprise
  each menu position
- **hw_inputopcrf** - cross-reference table to link
  hw_product and hw_inputop - illustrates which ingredients were bought
  with each buy document

I'm wondering if I'm missing some SQL syntax magic here, or it's at all not a good idea to do it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around with correlated queries and FROM-subqueries, which still did NOT give me what I wanted, I think I have found a workaround. Even though it leaves the original problem on its own, I think it even provides a better alternative than I was originally aiming at.

Note there is no union - I just selected another column which is to signify whether the data on all the ingredients is in place. Here it goes:

```
select hw_marketable.name as nm, hw_productcategory.name as pc, hw_marketable.price as p,
           round(sum(hw_inputopcrf.price*hw_prodcrf.spendquantity)::numeric, 2)::text as primecost,
           (case round(hw_marketable.price::numeric, 2) when 0.00 then '--' else
                 round((sum(hw_inputopcrf.price*hw_prodcrf.spendquantity)*100./hw_marketable.price::real)::numeric, 2)::text
           end) as primecost_percentage,
           case ((select count(productid) from hw_prodcrf where marketableid=hw_marketable.id)
                        -(select count(stapleid) from hw_inputopcrf, hw_prodcrf where productid=stapleid and marketableid=hw_marketable.id))
                   when 0 then 'OK'
                   else 'Insufficient data'
                   end,

                   (case hw_marketable.enabled when 0 then 'Inactive' else 'Active' end)
from hw_marketable inner join hw_prodcrf on marketableid=hw_marketable.id
     inner join hw_product on hw_product.id=productid
     inner join hw_inputopcrf on hw_inputopcrf.stapleid=hw_product.id
     inner join hw_inputop on hw_inputop.id=hw_inputopcrf.inputopid and
                hw_inputop.id=(
                  select id from hw_inputop, hw_inputopcrf
                  where hw_inputop.id=hw_inputopcrf.inputopid and hw_inputopcrf.stapleid=hw_prodcrf.productid
                        and hw_product.id=hw_prodcrf.productid order by dateclosed desc limit 1)
     inner join hw_productcategory on hw_productcategory.id=hw_marketable.productcategoryid
group by hw_marketable.id, nm, pc, p order by hw_marketable.name asc
```